# Convert string with special characters to URL in class file, in .net4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, url

I have a string below, need to convert it to URl in class file, it contains special characters.

```
"http://www.GenerateURL.com/try?origins=**Rue 66 & Rue Oued Draa / Rue 77, Tangier, Morocco**&destinations=**Boulevard Lalla Asmaa, Casablanca, Morocco**&language=en-EN&sensor=false"
```

Many Thanks

Comment: You mean to say replace special character.

Comment: I don't understand what "URl in class file" means.  Do you want to populate a C# class with the values, or encode as a URI?

Comment: yes replace special characters, in c# class file

Comment: There is nothing special about the characters you've shown... Use proper way to construct query string from duplicate bug and avoid any string format/concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()`. Here is the documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx

Comment: In c# class file, i cannot find HttpUtility

Comment: At top of your C# file, add `using System.Web;`

Comment: Use `WebUtility` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to use System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode for this:

```
string encodedString ="http://www.GenerateURL.com/try?origins=**Rue 66 & Rue Oued Draa / Rue 77, Tangier, Morocco**&destinations=**Boulevard Lalla Asmaa, Casablanca, Morocco**&language=en-EN&sensor=false";

 string real = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(encodedString);
```

Use Server.UrlEncode

You need an instance of the HttpServerUtility class, because the UrlEncode method is not static.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urlencode.aspx)